# Defining a two dimensional array

Tags: java

What is wrong with this definition? I want to declare a two dimensional array with those numbers:

```
int[][] arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
```

I get this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be:

```
int[][] arr = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

More information is available on JLS, see [10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of
>   expressions, enclosed by braces **{** and **}**.

You might also want to have a look at a basic [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), it'll help you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like so:

```
int[][] arr = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
```

Yout need to use curly brakets (`{ }`).

Answer (score 3):

You should use `{` and `}`, instead of `[` and `]` to initialize the array.